# Is there a way for me to center the LI in my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, navbar

I'm following this guide for a responsive navigation bar that works for mobile and for web
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-h8L5hgW-w&t=7225s
Sorry in advance if its a very easy solution.

Im struggling to center my navigation bar. Right now its placed left side.

```
<body>
    <!-- Navigation bar-->
    <div class="navbar">
        <img id="mobile-cta" class="mobile-menu" src="/images/open.svg" alt="Open Navigation">
        <nav>
            <img id="mobile-exit" class="mobile-menu-exit" src="../images/close.svg" alt="Close Navigation">
            <ul class="primary-nav">
                <li class="current"><a href="../html/index.html">Forside</> </a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="../html/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
<body>
```

That looks like this

[Picture of navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2CZ9.png)

[Picture of mobile version, this one is totally fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncQcF.png)

And this is my whole CSS for the navbar.

```
  /* Code for Navigation bar */
    .navbar {
        background: white;
        padding: 1em;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    
        /* Hides the navigation menu when on mobile */
        nav {
            display: none;
        }
    
    
        .mobile-menu {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        /* Defines distance from logo and if the list should have dots etc. */
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    }
    
    nav.menu-btn {
        display: block;
    }
    
      /* Mobile menu navigation */
    nav {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 66%;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        background: black;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 1em;
    
        ul.primary-nav {
            margin-top: 5em;
        }
    
        li {
            // Mobile menu text
            a {
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                padding: .5em;
                font-size: 1.5em;
                text-align: right;
    
                &:hover {
                    color: #1e73be;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0em 0;
    }
    
    // Controls the text after animation
    a::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        background-color: #1e73be;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
    }
    
    li a::after {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(0);
        transform-origin: center;
    }
    
    li a:hover::after,
    li a:focus::after {
        transform:scale(1);
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .mobile-menu-exit {
        float: right;
        margin: .5em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    // Controls when to switch from mobile to website view.
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    
        .mobile-menu,
        .mobile-menu-exit {
            display: none;
        }
    
        .navbar nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            background: none;
            position: unset;
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
          
            ul {
                display: flex;
                text-align: center;
            }
    
            a {
                color: black;
                font-size: 1em;
                padding: .1em 1em;
               
            }
            ul.primary-nav {
                margin: 0;
            }
    
            // CSS for the current tab in navbar for web
            li.current a {
    
                color: #1e73be;
            }
    
            li a {
                color: black;
                border: 3px;
                font-weight: bold;
                border-radius: 5em;
                margin-top: 0;
    
                &:hover {
                    color: #1e73be;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try this ul{width:100%; test-align:center;}

Comment: And you can also try this ul.primary-nav { display: flex;   align-items: center;   justify-content: center;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `min-width` media query on `.navbar nav` use `justify-content: center;` instead of `space-between` so that your `ul` is centered. Then set another media query instructing the same `width` but `max-width` and then change it back to `justify-content: space-between;` to position your logo.

I've added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/v7g1h4rm/4/) since you are using SCSS.